# A functional series as variation of the Basel problem (with roots)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, riemann-zeta

The Basel problem consisted in finding the sum in closed form of the following numerical series, of which was already known its convergence and its numerical value with arbitrary precision (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$$

The result was found by Euler about a hundred years later after the problem was posed for the first time.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\zeta(2)$$

where $\zeta(n)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Now, I would like to know what is the exact sum (in closed form) of the following functional series that, even if obviously different from the previous numerical series (even just for the fact that the previous is a numerical series while the following is a functional series), has in its structure the factor related to the Basel problem.

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{x^\frac{1}{n}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}}{n^2}\qquad\ \text{with}\quad x\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$$

I already know that the functional series is convergent, so I would kindly ask not to address that aspect: I just need the exact sum in closed form with the proof. Any other consideration or suggestion about how to proceed without the solution and the step-by-step proof would be useless; unless, of course, somebody can prove that there is something wrong in the question itself.

Thank you

-Update-

Here another way in which is possible to rewrite the functional series considered:
$$\\$$

$$\frac{\sqrt[n]{x}}{n^2}=\frac{x^\frac{1}{n}}{n^2}=
\frac{e^{\ln(x^\frac{1}{n})}}{n^2}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(x)}}{n^2}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}\ln(x)+\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{\ln^2(x)}{2!}+\frac{1}{n^3}\frac{\ln^3(x)}{3!}+\frac{1}{n^4}\frac{\ln^4(x)}{4!}+...}{n^2}=\\
=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\ln(x)+\frac{1}{n^4}\frac{\ln^2(x)}{2!}+\frac{1}{n^5}\frac{\ln^3(x)}{3!}+\frac{1}{n^6}\frac{\ln^4(x)}{4!}+...$$

hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{x^\frac{1}{n}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Biggl(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\ln(x)+\frac{1}{n^4}\frac{\ln^2(x)}{2!}+\frac{1}{n^5}\frac{\ln^3(x)}{3!}+\frac{1}{n^6}\frac{\ln^4(x)}{4!}+...\Biggr)=\\
=\zeta(2)+\zeta(3)\ln(x)+\zeta(4)\frac{\ln^2(x)}{2!}+\zeta(5)\frac{\ln^3(x)}{3!}+\zeta(6)\frac{\ln^4(x)}{4!}+...=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \zeta(n+1)\frac{\ln^{^{n-1}}(x)}{(n-1)!}=\\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \zeta(n+2)\frac{\ln^{^{n}}(x)}{n!}
\qquad\ \qquad\ \text{with}\quad x\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$$

Comment: Is there a reason to suspect it has a closed formula?

Comment: Your series are not especially connected with the Basel Problem.

Comment: To Thomas Andrews:

Unfortunately, not that I know. I just hope so. I don’t even know if, in general, there are cases in mathematics where is possible infer that there is a solution in the form of a closed formula.

Comment: To Jean Marie:
I specifically wrote: “[…] even if obviously different from the previous numerical series […]”: I know that they are two different thing. I was referring to the similarity of the structure; as well as has done another author, on this site, for another series in this article https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069709/basel-problem-but-with-cosines. Check the update: I found another way to rewrite that series that, maybe, could help.
Now the first term of the new sum is the result of the Basel problem; for me already just this would be enough to see some connection.

Comment: To reuns:I need a proof to accept the assertion (at least reference to the relative literature) that it doesn’t have a closed-form solution. You say that the other series that you present has solution linked to the even values of the Riemann zeta function, for which I know exist a closed form related to the Bernoulli numbers: can you give me all the possible info about this series that you have cited, because it seems that for $a=n\ln(x)$ it coincides with mine? Check the update: I found another way to rewrite that series that, togheter with your citation could lead to the solution. Thank you.

Comment: $\zeta(3)$ and $\zeta(2k+1)$ don't have a closed-form. I meant $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{a/n}+e^{-a/n}}{n^2}$ sorry, having a closed-form from the one for $\zeta(2k)$. My series doesn't have those odd terms.

Comment: To reuns:
I agree with you about the fact that, now, is not known a closed form that represents the value of the Riemann zeta function for odd integers. Nevertheless, this doesn’t prove that a series that contains in itself the Riemann zeta function evaluated for odd integers, or for all integers, cannot, altogether, return a result in closed form; like the examples in the following link, instead, show (among which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bigl(\zeta(2n+1)-1\Bigr)=\frac{1}{4}$ is the clearer): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Infinite_series